# Cordova - How to add multiple targets to build in build.json

Tags: json, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-3

We have build.json to provide the code signing keys to build the both iOS & Android like follows

```
    {
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Development",
            "provisioningProfile": "926c2bd6-8de9-4c2f-8407-1016d2d12954",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "development"
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
            "provisioningProfile": "70f699ad-faf1-4adE-8fea-9d84738fb306",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "app-store"
        }
    }
}
```

But in my case, I have multiple targets in cordova application. I want to build those by using the build.json. How can I add the multiple targets in build.json

Thanks

Comment: Hey, any one can share the answer ?

Comment: maybe try building manually?
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#xcode-build-flags

Comment: Then, what is the option for Android ?